# Why am I unable to zoom in on this UIImageView which is in a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm looking to present a `UIImageView` inside of a `UIScrollView` which can be zoomed in, then panned around and everything. All of this is being done in code without the use of IB.

I'm trying to add the image and scrollview as follows:

```
    self.imageBeingOverlayed = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:responseObject];
    self.imageBeingOverlayed.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    self.imageBeingOverlayedScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.imageBeingOverlayedScrollView.contentSize = ((UIImage *)responseObject).size;
    self.imageBeingOverlayedScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
    self.imageBeingOverlayedScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;

    [self.imageBeingOverlayedScrollView addSubview:self.imageBeingOverlayed];
    [darkOverlayView addSubview:self.imageBeingOverlayedScrollView];
```

Where I create the image view, I then add it to a scroll view I create (both of these objects are able to be accessed throughout the whole file). With the scrollview I create, I only want it to be as big as the image, but I'm confused how to create the frame. Maybe it's that.

But regardless, then I set the maximum and minimum zoom scales, I set the delegate of the scrollview to `self` in `viewDidLoad`, and I have this method implemented as well:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.imageBeingOverlayed;
}
```

But when I run the app and use a decently large image the image can be panned, but not zoomed in at all. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, the scrollView's delegate had not been set prior to setting `minimumZoomScale` and `maximumZoomScale`. In that case, the call to `viewForZoomingInScrollView` doesn't work because the delegate is still `nil`. To solve it, try setting `contentSize`, `minimumZoomScale` and `maximumZoomScale` after the delegate is set in your code:

```
self.imageBeingOverlayedScrollView.delegate = self;
self.imageBeingOverlayedScrollView.contentSize = self.imageBeingOverlayed.image.size;
self.imageBeingOverlayedScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
self.imageBeingOverlayedScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
```